# Problema con For aninado

Tags: java, bucle-for

!Buenas!

Estoy haciendo una prueba para un pequeño proyecto. Tengo un código sencillo, pero me esta dando un problema y lo he intentado solucionar pero no encuentro el porque.

Aquí el código:

```
public void identificarManoJ1() {    
    int pareja = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j<5; j++) {
            if((pareja < 2) && manoJ1[i].equalsIgnoreCase(manoJ1[j])) {
                pareja++;
            }  
        }
    }

    if(pareja == 2) {
        System.out.print(" Tiene una pareja.");
    }
}
```

Esta parte esta dentro de un método. La idea es que de una baraja aleatoria que creo (Un simple **array** de 5), quiero que verifique que hay 2 cartas iguales, y se sume a un contador. Para verificar si lo que tiene esa "mano" es una pareja, al estilo **Poker**.

**Problema**:

Siempre me dice `Tiene una pareja`. Creo que el problema viene del bucle que esta sumando mal algo, pero sinceramente no encuentro el qué.

**Aquí genero la mano:**

```
public void generarJ1() {

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {

        aleatorio =(int) (Math.random()*13);

        manoJ1[i] = baraja[aleatorio];

    }

}
```

**Y así tengo definida la baraja:**

```
private final String [] baraja = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"};
```

**Y este es uno de los resultados que me devuelve:**

```
Mano de Jugador 1: [7][8][6][9][2] Tiene una pareja.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i<(5-1); i++) {
    for(int j = (i+1); j<5; j++) {  //nótese que estoy cambiando j=1 por j=(i+1)
        if (manoJ1[i].equalsIgnoreCase(manoJ1[j])) {
                pareja++;
             }
       }
    }
}
if(pareja > 0) {
    System.out.print(" Tiene por lo menos una pareja.");
}
```

Comment: Me ayudo bastante. Muchas gracias!!